# Can someone help with memory leak problem?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm a newbie trying to figure out a memory leak problem. Does anyone see anything wrong with the following code?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:.20 blue:0.30 alpha:1]];
}
```

In case it helps, Instruments shows the leaked block with the following info...

Event Type: Malloc

Responsible Library: CoreGraphics

Responsible Caller: CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I'm still very new, so please explain in as much detail as possible.)

Much thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant programming language.

Comment: Do you use the Malloc() function in your code?

Comment: No, I haven't used the Malloc() function directly. It's possible it is used in a framework or something, but it's not something that I've used directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a long shot but I'm not sure if it was just a bug in my project or not but I had a similar issue once when setting `tintColor` in `viewWillAppear`. I ended up adding an `nil` check before assigning the color again and this cleared it up for me (I didn't do any further investigation into it so I could be wrong).

```
if (nil == self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor) {
  self.navigationController.navigationBar = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:.20 blue:0.30 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Paul. I narrowed the memory problem for sure to the code above even though it seems to be okay. I have kept various versions of the project throughout the process and the memory leak was introduced when the above code was added. I tried your solution and it worked. I'm ever so grateful!

Comment: I was able to fix a similar leak simply by setting the navigationBar's `tintColor` inside `-viewWillAppear:` instead of `-viewDidLoad:`... odd.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is correct, as far as memory management is concerned.

Instruments Leaks will simply show the point where the leaked object is allocated, not the point where it is actually leaked.

So, your leak is elsewhere. Looking at your code, I would say that the leak is possibly occurring when you release the class containing that code, or elsewhere along the dynamical path to `dealloc`.

Try commenting out `setTintColor` to check whether the leak is still there.

Hope this explanation can put you on the right track, but in any case, if you need more help, you should post more code...

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a tough time narrowing this one down. If you have a sec, please pass on any other helpful pointers so I can get this resolved. My understanding is that I have only to worry about three things (1) alloc, (2) copy-not an issue, (3) retain. This is correct, right? Also, 'retain' does not refer to @property/synthesize since the system handles these items, right? Thanks again for any help.